# Unable to do a Nuxt axios post

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

I have spent some hours trying to figure out my problem without any success.

before reading the explanation

---

My nuxt site generates dynamic content and works well on client side but for SEO to work and social media shares render dynamic content i need to move my app to SSR. This axios post request do work on client side rendering but does not on SSR and I don't understand the reason and I need help to understand it.

Thanks

---

For starters I am building a Nuxt app that consumes Drupal as a CMS using a fully decoupled approach and I have been using it for several VUE apps without problem and now I need to do them on Nuxt with a SSR approach because I need heavy SEO on the sites. With Nuxt the same request against oauth/token on drupal doesn't work and I have gone from the complex structure we had to the simple one using both Axios and Nuxt/Axios without any success and alway getting a **400 error code**.

I need to run this code first on my app so I can get drupal access token and do some request for data.

Code on store

```
export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit({dispatch}, vuexContext, context, app){
    
    await dispatch("setToken");
  },
async setToken({ commit, dispatch, getters }, context) {
      //prep form data to send
      const FormData = require('form-data');
      const body = new FormData();
      body.append("param1", apiConfig.getValue("param1"));
      body.append("param2", apiConfig.getValue("param2"));
      body.append("param3", apiConfig.getValue("param3"));
      body.append("param4", apiConfig.getValue("param4"));
      body.append("param5", apiConfig.getValue("5"));

      
      await this.$axios.$post(url, body)
               .then(({data}) => {
                   //code to process data
                   commit("SET_TOKEN_DATA", data);
                }).catch(error => {

                  console.log(error)
                 }).finally(() => {
       
                 console.log("FINALY");
                 });;

}
```

Some updates

base url is defined on nuxt.config as

```
// module options for axios
  axios: {
    baseURL: 'mysite.com'
  },
```

I have tied  on http request the following request using both axios and nuxt/axios, I will write short request just to show what I edid

```
await this.$axios.$post('mysite.com/oauth/token', body)

await this.$axios.$post('/oauth/token', body)

await this.$axios.$post('oauth/token', body)
```

I have also tried to use

```
const api = $axios.crate({
baseURL: 'url'
})

api.$axios.post('oauth/token', body)
```

---

another updated

Crated a Client Side Nuxt app and the request works.

Comment: What is `const FormData = require('form-data');` doing ? Pretty sure this is not something that should be here.

Comment: Also, check your network tab, is everything fine there ?

Comment: network returns nothing since it's SSR and executing on nuxtServerInit. FormData is used on const body = new FormDara();

Comment: Oops right ! Try making it on client at first to debug it IMO. If it works fine on client, it will be a step further. ;D You don't need to require anything for a `FormData` as far as I know: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData

Comment: thanks, i will test that. even though that being said, I tested the request using requestbin and it arrives equally as if posted from postman or vue app.

Comment: @kissu solved my issue, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Fix it, after literally 16 hours trying. When multiform post data you need to send FormData headers on the post and again, this works without any issues using CSR on VUE and Nuxt.

```
await this.$axios.$post(url, body, { headers: body.getHeaders()}).yada
```

I don't know if it's Axios or Nuxt the one doing this but I followed a breadcrumb trail to this post https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/318